# Reformatting date with Javascript

Tags: javascript

(Updated for clarity!)

I need to implement a JS countdown timer through a rather inelegant solution and stumbled upon a particular challenge (I'm not a developer and out of my depth here).

On this page (https://jsbin.com/guxijofuca/edit?html,js,output) I want to extract the date from the HTML element, then apply/use it in the countdown plugin. However, the date exists in the following format: Apr 12, 2022 14:12

The plugin requires the code in this format:

```
// SET DATE TO SPECIFIC DAY IN THE FUTURE
// MONTHS go from 0 to 11: January is 0, February is 1, and so on
var then = new Date(2022, 11, 25, 15, 30, 0, 0);
```

Would someone be able to help me convert the above time into the format that's needed for the plugin?

Comment: what is the `goaltime` html element ?

Comment: "*I don't even know what that format is called*" It's not a "format" *per se*, but the [constructor for the JavaScript `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#constructor). As such you can replace everything to the right of the `=` with any expression that returns a `Date` object which represents the date you're after. Why not just set the value of `then` directly to what you've got in `countDownDate`, since `Date.parse` *should* return a `Date`...?

Comment: [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) can parse that date as-is, which in turn can be used to create a `Date` object. It will be in the client's local time zone, however, which may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You only need assign that parsed countdown to a new `Date` class

```js
var countDownDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("goaltime").innerHTML);

const then = new Date(countDownDate);

console.log(countDownDate);
console.log(then);
```

```html
<div id="goaltime">Apr 28, 2022 15:03</div>
```

> The `Date` class actually can receive a single argument. There are many ways to make a new `Date` class object.

> **Some useful refrerences**: [W3Schools Date](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp), [MDN-Docs Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#examples), and [W3Schools Date parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parse.asp)

Comment: Thank you! I just don't know how to implement it in the plugin, sorry. I'm out of my depth here.  What lines to I replace in the plugin?

Comment: what plugin/package do you use? is it something like `moment.js`, `dayjs`, or something like that? And whats your exact goal?

Comment: See the preview link in the original post above please.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a `Date` object already in `countDownDate`, why even bother creating that when you can set `then` to that value straight away?

```
var then = Date.parse(document.getElementById("goaltime").innerHTML);
```

This is assuming what you mentioned in your post is true and that the initial `Date.parse` operation doesn't return any exceptions based on the `innerHTML` content of the `#goaltime` element to the `Date` initially.

Comment: Sorry, I explained this badly. Again, I'm not a developer. I'm out of my depth here. Here's a preview of what I'd like to achieve. The date is on the page and the JS plugin needs to pick up that date and use it somehow. I'm struggling to extract and convert the date so that the plugin works. https://jsbin.com/guxijofuca/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the string with Date.parse which returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. Then create a Date object with that.

```
const parsedDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("goaltime").innerHTML);
const then = new Date(parsedDate);
```

If you need to alter the parsed date components at all you can break it down like this (adding or subtracting whatever you need to each component of the final new Date):

```
const parsedDate = Date.parse(document.getElementById("goaltime").innerHTML);
const tempDate  = new Date(parsedDate);
const then = new Date(tempDate.getFullYear(), tempDate.getMonth(), tempDate.getDate(), tempDate.getHours(), tempDate.getMinutes(), tempDate.getSeconds(), tempDate.getMilliseconds());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods on `Date` to get year, month etc. Then pass these to plugin

```js
//var dt = Date.parse(document.getElementById("goaltime").innerHTML);
const dt = new Date()

const year = dt.getFullYear();
const month = dt.getMonth();
const date = dt.getDate();
const hours = dt.getHours();
const mins = dt.getMinutes();

console.log({ year, month, date, hours, mins });
```